# How to make a separate RSS feed for each entry type of a section?

Tags: entry-type, rss

I would like to make a separate RSS feed for each entry type of a section, for example:

http://mysite.com/posts/feed.rss

http://mysite.com/videos/feed.rss

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rey - depending on how you've setup your enries and folder structure you could create feed.rss as a template in both of those folders.

Inside the template you can setup the entry loop to output whatever information you need the RSS feed to include. It's not automated but completely within your control.

Comment: Hmm nice! Is it possible to exclude certain entry types from the section rss feed? (should I create another question?!)

Comment: Sure inside the feed.rss it would use twig just like anything other template. Just call and limit/filter your entries like you normally would - http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to click accept my answer so we keep our answer % up. :)